# Image Clipping Parent Element's Border-Radius? (Safari)

Tags: html, css, border, clipping

What causes an image to clip a parenting element's `border-radius`? Both the image and the parent element have a `border-radius: 50%` applied, but it still causes the clipping to occur.

This is the issue I am facing in Safari:

[image]

It seems to be a Safari-specific issue, from what I can see. Any input?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#photo-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 40px 25% 20px;
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#photo-container a {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img#photo {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="photo-container">
  <a id="#">
    <img id="photo" src="http://freedesignfile.com/upload/2018/02/most-beautiful-scenery-of-nature-Stock-Photo-04.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: What if you try to create an empty DIV instead and set the image as a background, then see if border radius on that div creates the same issue.

Comment: Tried your suggestion, didn't work out. I feel like there should be a simple solution to this, but maybe it's a bug in Safari?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "didn't work out". Does this not look like an image with circle in Safari? https://jsfiddle.net/jsbd8zd7/

Comment: @Alexus, appreciate the feedback, though I was able to find a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48877520/9214076.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. Applying `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` and `-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;` to `img#photo` resolved the border clipping issue.

```
img#photo {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When initially loading the page, it displays that slight overlap error until the page is fully loaded, and then it's loading correctly in safari for me.[image]

The only suggestion I can make, if you're still seeing the issue, is to add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `#photo-container a` as well.

As far as why it's happening, This is why:

[image]

It seems Safari has trouble cropping the image correctly. so the border of the container is getting covered up by the image, even though the image isn't visible. I tested a couple different things, such as reducing the size of the image, etc, and had similar issues at multiple stages, so this is unlikely to be something you can 100% account for.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the issue still persists, even with `box-sizing: border-box` applied to `#photo-container a`.

Comment: So, would this be considered a browser display bug then?